# Serial communication from arduino to Linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, arduino

I have been trying to print the serial output from the Arduino to the Linux terminal but the output sent to the terminal seems to be empty with string as shown in the figure below

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);

void loop() {
float zby = 4.54;
 Serial.println(zby);
delay(1000);
}
```

[image: the output of the serial in the linux terminal in windows]

I have tried using Raspberry Pi so I connected the Arduino to the raspberry and did the same thing but at least i found something received
[image: The output of the serial from raspberry pi][The ports that i have used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFChG.png)

[The Arduino code and terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uomNL.png)

Comment: How do you know it connected as `/dev/ttyS0`?

Comment: I have used the command ls -l /dev/tty to list out all the ports @TimRoberts

Comment: you are using a baudrate of 115200 in your linux, but the arduino is sending at 9600

Answer (score 0):

I think you havent set the baudrate properly. On arduino you set it to 9600 but on pc its 115200. The baud rate needs to be the same on the sending and the recieving side.

Comment: The baud rate is assigned correctly it's just that i forgot to change the picture when I snap it

Comment: Might be a charset issue then. It seems you are recieving something so communication is happening. Arduino uses ASCII. Check what charset the terminal is expecting

Comment: I have also tried to disconnect the Arduino and still reading empty